# Default locale doesn't change in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, locale, symfony4

I'm trying to change locale from 'en' to 'lt' as a default, but not changing at all it only adds as a "Fallback locale", but not as a main. So following that problem I'm getting another one, that routes by language is incorrect. So the first problem should solve all others.

services.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'lt'
```

framework.yaml

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
```

and results:

[image]

[image]

So by that my Routes using EN language routes instead LT

Any solutions? tried without %locale% variables, clearing cache etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using translations, have a look in **translations.yaml** :

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

The %locale% variable is defined in **services.yaml**.

If you're using an [event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) to track a user defined locale you might want to check that event subscriber's config in **services.yaml** :

```
 App\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber:
    arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
```